# Convert array to typescript options

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am wondering if it would be possible to use an array of strings/integers as options for a typescript interface. For example:

```
const numbers = [50,100,200,300,400,500];
interface INumbers {
    numbersType:numbers --> (should be 50 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500)
}
```

Please let me know if this is possible and how one would do this!

Thanks!

Comment: Try `const arr = [1,2,3] as const`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Comment: @zero298 no sadly:(, if I put number: 50 it says 'number' is not assignable to type 'readonly [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

```
type numbers = [50,100,200,300,400,500];
interface INumbers {
    numbersType:numbers;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work :(. Says number is not assignable to numbers (the array you created)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [50,100,200,300,400,500] as const;

interface INumbers {
    numbersType: (typeof numbers)[number]
}

const passes: INumbers = {
    numbersType: 50 // WORKS
};

const fails: INumbers = {
    numbersType: 51 // FAILS
};
```